# How to make a jquery script to restart?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, restart

I've made a jQuery script that makes a slide show of two div elements.
Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#slide2").hide();
    $("div#slide1").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500,function(){
    $("div#slide2").fadeIn(1500).show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500)
    });
});
```

Now my question. How to make this script to restart everytime it is finished?

Comment: It's not the answer to your question, but if you are just trying to loop through a number of pictures use the jQuery plugin [cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

Answer (score 2):

Create a function `foo`, and set it as the callback of the last animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#slide2").hide();
    (function foo() {
        $("div#slide1").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500,function(){
            $("div#slide2").fadeIn(1500).show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500, foo);
        });
    }());
});
```

Comment: +1, your solution works much better as timing is important in this instance.`http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/cNRW3/` I tried `setInterval()` and the timing was just off. Well Done.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an infinitely recursed function that calls itself upon completion of the animations.

```
function animation() {
    $("div#slide2").hide();
    $("div#slide1").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500,function(){
        $("div#slide2").fadeIn(1500).show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500, function() {
            animation();
        });
    });
}
```

And then call it within document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() { animation(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**setTimeout**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) :

```
function foo()
{
    $("div#slide2").hide();
    $("div#slide1").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500,function()
    {
        $("div#slide2").fadeIn(1500).show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
    });

    setTimeout(foo, 0);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    foo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code into the function, then call this function after it's completed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    slideshow();


    function slideshow(){
        $("div#slide2").hide();
        $("div#slide1").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500,function(){
            $("div#slide2").fadeIn(1500).show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500,function(){
                slideshow();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

here is the demo [on the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FsH2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var repeat = function(time) {

   var 
       refForStop = true,
       fnrepeat = function() {
          $("div#slide2").hide();
          $("div#slide1").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500,function(){
             $("div#slide2").fadeIn(1500).show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1500)
          });

          if (refForStop) {
             setTimeout(fnrepeat, time || 1000);
          }
       };

   fnrepeat();
   return function() { refForStop = false; };
};


$(document).ready(function(){

    var fnStop = repeat();
    //run function for stop: fnStop();

});
```